# Identity Token-Based token expire after 15 min on server but work on local

Tags: angularjs, authentication, oauth, asp.net-identity, access-token

I use identity token-based and angularjs in my project, The token works properly in the local environment but expires in the server after 15 minutes. I set AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDay(14) in middleware and check expire_in value in token, expire_in:1209599 equal to 14 day.

**Apparently everything is right**

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() {

            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

My server is Plesk

My Questions :

**1- Should I set this setting(Expire Timeout) elsewhere?**
[OAuth2 WebApi Token Expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701398/oauth2-webapi-token-expiration)

**2- Do you really have to use RefreshToken?**
http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

**3- Should I Config Plesk ???**

**4- Is related to the virtual server and machine key ???** 
[asp.net identity expire bearer token after 20 min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143794/asp-net-identity-expire-bearer-token-after-20-min)

**Thank you for more details**

Comment: Can you check your your generated token in a place like jwt.io and see if the expiration time is equal to 14 days? How are you sure that works on local but does now work on server?

Comment: jwt.io can't decode my token, Is the token generated by the machine key ? I use virtual host .. Maybe that's because ?

Comment: I think your host does not have any role on the token. The key is used for signing the token.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the exact same problem with my server while it's working locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Amin said, it is correct

you must generate a appropriate machine key and add to your project's web.config.

you can generate machine key in : http://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx

so, i have generated key as following :

```
<machineKey validationKey="4E6D929B83FD607A895C1E65DDEB9E76E67D06291A040817EF59FBE59126ECA038266C20D8D649C94838A4157D40A9DAE3070755EF31AED17BC39DF0BD1D88CD" decryptionKey="83B540F6E86C959734C7C053A97F15E07AC7789100D26E7420B70597C66A84CD" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

and added inside `<system.web>` tag.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

i resolve this after a while.
you must **generate a appropriate machine key** and add to your project's web.config.

you can generate machine key in : http://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx

Comment: very nice, i had same issue and now resolved. instead of other site reference i have added answer to following answer.